# Spring boot camel unmarshal json list of objects that have ZonedDateTime field

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-camel

I have 2 different camel routes.

1)

```java
from(...).routeId(...)
  .unmarshal().json(SomeClass.class)
  ....;
```

And
2)

```java
from(...).routeId(...)
  .unmarshal(new ListJacksonDataFormat(SomeOtherClass.class))
  ....;
```

Both `SomeClass` and `SomeOtherClass` have field named timestamp whose type is `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

In first route I pass single object and it unmarshals without errors. In 2nd route I pass a list of objects and it does not work:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Java 8 date/time type `java.time.ZonedDateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling

Questions:

1. Do I correctly understand that if I want to unmarshal list I need to use `.unmarshal(new ListJacksonDataFormat(...))` instead of `.unmarshal().json(...)`?
2. Do I really need to add Module `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310`? Otherwise I would have added it without even asking here but since my first route can manage ZonedDateTime just fine I wanted to be sure that I really have to add a new module or if there are any other means of dealing with it? It's strange that first route can unmarshal ZonedDateTime fine and 2nd can't.

After `.unmarshal(...)` I plan to call `.bean(..., "method")` where method takes List as argument. Not sure if this extra info is needed but added it just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely issue is that in the first example the actual json which you are trying to unmarshal does not include a timestamp so jackson will not try to unmarshal a field of type `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

If it is your intention that the object be unmarshalled with the timestamp field populated you should add `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310` to your project.

Comment: Thanks! How do tell this 2nd option to use xstream library too?

Comment: The `ListJacksonDataFormat` class is specifically for jackson, if you use this class you will use jackson.  If you want to use xstream just use the first option.

Comment: Thanks, it was because in 2nd case I had list and I could not just write List<MyClass>.class as argument for .json() method.

Comment: I will edit the answer to try to make it better answer the question